# Missing touch option in Rails has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 Rails models: Book and Category, where a book `belongs_to` a category, a category `has_many` books.

The category name is shown in each book's page, and pages are cached.

If I change a category name (say, from 'Sci Fi' to 'Science Fiction'), then all corresponding book pages will be stale, and books need to be "touched" in order to trigger HTML regeneration.

It would seem to make sense to be able to do:

```
class Category << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, touch: true
end
```

But [the option is unavailable](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/xiHmKDIcLi0), I guess because the `touch` mechanism would instantiate each object, which could result in a major performance hit for `has_many` relationships.

To avoid that, I am using raw SQL as follows:

```
class Category << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  after_update -> {
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE books SET updated_at='#{current_time_string}' WHERE category_id=#{id})"
  }
end
```

Which is pretty terrible.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `touch` on `has_many` association, it works only with `belongs_to`, that's a fact.

If I understand correctly what you want, the answers with `touch:true` in the Book model won't work, because the Book object will not be updated when You change the Category model and the view will not regenerating.

So I think your solution is the best for that. (You can use also `books.update_all(updated_at: Time.now)`)

Comment: You are right on both counts: 1) I do need to change all books when a category changes; 2) update_all is more straightforward and does NOT instantiate the models; the SQL query sent straight to the DB avoids performance issues.

Comment: Note that `update_all` does not fire ActiveRecord callbacks.  So if your Book model has another `belongs_to ... touch: true` relationship, that touch will not occur.  You would need to also trigger that manually.

Comment: UPDATE - as of Rails 6 `has_one` will also support `touch: true`, see relevant commit https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3fe83d1dd99ac2662852da0dcfe7e91dc08ae160.

Answer (score 10):

As of Rails 6, there is a touch_all method available on ActiveRecord::Relation that handles this sort of thing with one query.  There is a pretty good blog article on it [here](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/08/27/rails-6-touch_all-method.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is only available on the `belongs_to` method which should be in your books model.  So you can still use it.

Comment: Lol, answered at the same time, the other answer has much better explanation :).